# Pointing 2 different paths to the same Apache domain name

Tags: apache-httpd

Can we configure apache in such a way that we can point 2 different applications to the same domain name with the last part of the url changing accordingly.

example:

> APP 1 - test.example.com/app1
>    APP 2 - test.example.com/app2
>
> test.example.com/app1 - should point to different DocumentRoot and Directory
>   test.example.com/app2  - should point to different DocumentRoot and Directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "Apache Module `mod_alias`" for this purpose. It is by default present in `/etc/httpd/modules/` directory.

To configure your alias using this module please take help from [this link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) provided by Apache.

Eg. In my office we are using one apache server for multiple sites.

```
[root@web ~]# cd /etc/httpd/conf.d/
```

To see first 5 lines I am using `head` command on three differnt configuration files.
1. nagvis.conf

```
[root@web conf.d]# head -n 5 nagvis.conf
# NagVis Apache2 sample configuration file
#
# #############################################################################

Alias /nagvis "/usr/local/nagvis/share"
```

2. pnp4nagios.conf

```
[root@web conf.d]# head -n 5 pnp4nagios.conf
# SAMPLE CONFIG SNIPPETS FOR APACHE WEB SERVER

Alias /pnp4nagios "/usr/local/pnp4nagios/share"

<Directory "/usr/local/pnp4nagios/share">
```

3. sarg.conf

```
[root@web conf.d]# head -n 5 sarg.conf 
Alias /sarg /var/www/sarg

<Directory /var/www/sarg>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    Order deny,allow
```

And after this when I want to open any link I just enter the Alias name following to the domain. Like: http://web.cmc.com/sarg OR http://web.cmc.com/pnp4nagios

If you are using phusion passenger [this link](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rack_to_sub_uri) may be helpful.

Comment: So, in the same virtual host I should create a alias  ?

Comment: I have edited my answer for your clarification

Comment: Should I make any changes to the Directory index settings?

Comment: no you only need to add `Alias </lastPart> </full/domain_path>` line, before (not inside) `<Directory /full/domain/path/>`

Comment: I tried the above configuration, but did not work. We are using a ruby on rails stack with apache and phusion passenger configuration, if that helps

Comment: @KarthikK Refer Answer Update.